# Accessing ssh from outside LAN where the public IP of ISP is ambiguous

Tags: networking, server, ssh, lan

So I have an ssh running on my RPi on local lan, and want to access it outside my home network. I already set up port forwarding on my modem, and in fact couple of years ago I was able to access it just fine using a free DDNS. But since sometime, it has not been made possible since my public IP itself has become ambiguous it seems.

On my modem's home page (192.168.1.1), the public IP there seems to be different than what is being seen by the outsde world. Feels like my ISP itself is running its own local network. Is there any solution to this? Maybe a third party broker in between who my RPi can handshake to and I can then access that broker in turn?

Comment: Google what is my ip address and what do you see?

Comment: Yes, probably your ISP is running another NAT outside your home NAT (this is usually called _carrier-grade NAT_). You need an external server (for example in Amazon cloud or similar) and you need to connect to this server via ssh from your RPi and set up a ssh tunnel so that port for example 2222 on that server will be forwarded to port 22 on your RPi (or any other port that you need). It's best to wrap it up on a script running on RPi that will detect possible disconnection and reconnect (otherwise in case of disconnect you will lose access to your RPi until you reconnect manually at home).